# "Please wait" message with delay

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I have a long task and I show "please wait" message during its execution.
I use SwingWorker for it. But sometimes long task is not long, so I want to show message with 1 second delay, but I don't know how to do it.

```
SwingWorker<Void, Void> mySwingWorker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){
     @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws InterruptedException 
        /** Execute some operation */   
    }
    @Override
    protected void done() {
        dialog.dispose();
    }
  };

  mySwingWorker.execute();

  JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
  progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
  JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  panel.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  panel.add(new JLabel("Please wait......."), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
  dialog.add(panel);
  dialog.pack();
  dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(win);
  dialog.setVisible(true);
```

}

Comment: Use a Swing Timer set to one second delay with no repeats, when the work stops, stop the Timer, if the Timer is triggered, show your popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start the `SwingWorker`, start a Swing `Timer` with (at least) a one second delay and set not to repeat.

Pass this `Timer` to your `SwingWorker` so it has access to it.  When the worker's `done` method is called, stop the `Timer`

If the `Timer` is triggered, you would display your wait message.

With a little bit of effort, you could wrap the whole thing up in a self contained class, using the `SwingWorker`'s `PropertyListener` support to detect when the worker was started and completed

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use `Thread.sleep(1000);` between each display of "please wait"

Comment: So either the going to block the EDT, which what the op has been trying to avoid, or cause the Swingaworker to ALWAYS to one second

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it would be to set

```
    long startTime = System.getNanoTime();
```

then before displaying the "please wait" you could check if it was > 1 second (1×10^9 nanos)

this may not be the most efficient way, but it will work